# MonkeyTalk string index out of range error

Tags: testing, monkeytalk

I am new to monkeytalk IDE. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and using monkeytalk latest version as testing tool to test a ios app. I have created a script for testing. But When I am going to save the script file, it is showing me below error.

```
Save Failed String index out of range: -1
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this. Any help is appreciable.